# How Many Ways Tic-Tac-Toe m*n grid that finnaly ended with draw position?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

For the variant of tic-tac-toe played on an $m\times n$ board, where you win if you completely fill any row or column with your mark (no diagonal wins), how many possibilities are there for the final board of a drawn game?

Example for $m=n=3$:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | O | O |
| O | X | X |
| X | O | O |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the grid is not square, how do you define a diagonal win?

Comment: @coffeemath But you can win either vertically or horizontally .

Comment: What I mean is, in the nonsquare case, is a win *only* if a horizontal or vertical row/column of same mark. That is, one dosn't consider any kind of slanted win in the non-square case. Is that right?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes it's

Comment: So to be clear: You now have said it is a "variant" of tic-tac-toe for which, even in the square case, you only count horozontal or vertical rows of same mark (not diagonals even in square case). So in 3 by 3 case would the identity matrix be counted as a draw since each row or column contains at least one 1 or 0 [viewing 1,0 as X,O]?